# Fluid design creates uneven columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, fluid-layout

I have a two column layout for displaying videos (without using the columns for this particular task, as I am already using columns with another sidebar and this content section that is causing me problems with fluid layouts, in particular within the second column, I currently have it display with two columns.

It generally renders just fine, with a bit of custom CSS just to fix alignments and such - .

My problem lies with headers such as in `<h4>{{video.title}}</h4>` being of different length, and so when the browser gets resized, it pushes the other content down, causing the direct parent div to increase in height, which then results in increasing the height of the top level div it is contained in with ng-repeat (which only repeats the div through a JS array - it is an [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org) directive, and irrelevant to the question).  As a result, it pushes any div below it off to the right, and the effect results in an empty spot that is slightly smaller than for a div, ruining what otherwise would be a clean column layout.

**HTML**

```
<div id="VideoContent" class="span9">
    <h3>Browse {{languageSelected}} Videos<span ng-hide="hasDifficulty(difficultySelected)"> ({{difficultySelected}})</span></h3>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="VideoSummary span4" ng-repeat="(videoIndex, video) in videos | filter: filterResults">
            <div class="VideoInfo">
                <div>
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <img alt="Video Preview Image" src="./images/video1.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h4>{{video.title}}</h4>
                        <p>Language:  {{video.language}}</p>
                        <p>Difficulty Level:  {{video.difficulty}}</p>
                        <p>Topics:  <span ng-repeat="(topicIndex, topic) in video.topics">{{topic}}<span ng-hide="isLastTopic(topicIndex, video.topics)">, </span></span></p>
                        <p>Contributor:  {{video.origin.creator}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>{{video.description}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="MiscInfo">
                <div>
                    <p class="pull-right label">{{video.views}} views</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="pull-right label" ng-show="hasTranslation(video)">Translate</p>
                    <p class="pull-right label" ng-show="hasCaption(video)">Caption</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS (SASS)**

```
> div#VideoContent
  > div
    > div.VideoSummary
      display: inline-block
      margin-top: 20px
      &:first-child
        margin-left: 2.5%
      > div.VideoInfo
        > div
          > div
            display: inline-block
          > div:last-child
            margin-left: 30px
            > p
              line-height: 10px
        > p
          margin-top: 20px
      > div.MiscInfo
        border-top-width: 1px
        border-top-color: $Blue
        border-top-style: dotted
        padding-top: 10px
        > div
          display: inline
        > div:first-child
          margin-right: 10%
          > p
            float: left
        > div:last-child
          > p:last-child
            margin-right: 10px
```

I know the sass isn't the cleanest atm, I plan on cleaning it up (such as removing those dreaded child selectors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, that's some very messy code!

The container of the problematic h4 (with your terrible code i can only reference it as "a div that's the fifth-level child of #VideoContent") has `display` set to `inline-block`.

An inline block becomes as wide as its content would be.

To make its width different from how wide it's content tries to be, you have to declare the width explicitly:

```
...
          > div
            display: inline-block
            width:   15em
...
```

If you want to keep your layout fluid then you should not use `inline-block` in the first place. Stay with `block` both for all containers and children. Set the width of the container explicitly. To create two columns, float the first column and add a left margin to the second column.

Your code is a total wreck, so i wrote a clean example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/z6Gsh/2/

PS Your only excuse can be that both HTML and CSS are provided by CMS, you're not allowed to  modify it and you are forced to override a lot of CSS. If you wrote that HTML by yourself then...
[image: Your code is bad and you should feel bad.]

### UPD 2013-03-28

Oh, so you need to prevent the item grow vertically?

Here you go, maintaining your crappy code structure:

```
$img-width: 200px
$Blue: blue

div#VideoContent
  width: 580px // You won't need this
  outline: 1px solid red
  > div
    > div.VideoSummary
      margin-top: 20px
      &:first-child
        margin-left: 2.5%
      > div.VideoInfo
        > div
          > div
            h4, p
              white-space: nowrap // Forcing the paragraphs be one line
              overflow-x: hidden // Trimming the lines 
              text-overflow: ellipsis // Adding three dots
              line-height: 1em // Fixing ridiculous line height
              margin: 0.5em // Fixing margins
          .pull-left
            float: left // The image is pulled to the left
          > div:last-child
            margin-left: $img-width + 30px // The text is pushed to the right
        > p
          margin-top: 20px
          clear: both // The text below the image should not start to the right of it
      > div.MiscInfo
        border-top-width: 1px
        border-top-color: $Blue
        border-top-style: dotted
        padding-top: 10px
        > div
          display: inline
        > div:first-child
          margin-right: 10%
          > p
            float: left
        > div:last-child
          > p:last-child
            margin-right: 10px

// This is for example
.pull-left
  width: $img-width
  height: 130px
  background-color: pink
```

The idea is simple. Use `white-space: nowrap` to force the text one-line, use `oveflow-x: hidden` to trim it and use `text-overflow: ellipsis` to add the three dots.

And these are the changes to fix for your ugly two column alignment:

1. For god's sake, remove all `display: inline-block` declarations, they are completely unnecessary and break the layout.
2. Apply `float-left` to the image (`.pull-left`).
3. Apply `margin-left: $img-width + 30px` to the description (`> div:last-child`), where `$img-width` is the width of the image.

Yay! It works as a charm:

http://d.pr/i/9Ma3+

You can fiddle with it here: http://fiddlesalad.com/sass/example-for-stack/

Don't forget to completely rewrite your HTML and apply CSS semantically, without those `>` hierarchies. Every time your present code is displayed in a browser, somewhere on Earth a kitten dies a painful death.

Comment: I acknowledge it's terrible, but I was mainly focused on getting a working layout & did not want to bother with some gotchas with CSS ruining styling.  I know how to use floats to create a two column layout - my problem is more subtle, and the HTML above is serving as a template since the number of each of these divs is yet to be determined

The fiddle did not address my main problem, which is probably trickier for someone to answer without me providing a fiddle of my own unfortunately.  My current solution is to use an Angular filter to control the character size in the text elements.

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: The problem is the text in the h4 or p elements can be of varying sizes, and so with a fluid layout, the text can be pushed down into another line depending on window size, which causes the repeated div it is contained in to increase in height and push a div on the next line over to the right, leaving a blank space where a div would normally appear neatly.  My current solution is to control the length of the text via JavaScript and append ... to the truncated text through a custom Angular filter I wrote, which does solve the problem, but I was hoping for a more elegant pure CSS solution.

Comment: Oh, so you need to prevent the item from growing vertically? I've edited my answer to address that. Don't forget to upvote and accept.